# Using MS PowerShell ISE to query json data

Tags: json, powershell

I have a text file containing json data and looks like this:

```
{ 
  "field1":"value1",
  "field2": [
      { 
         "subfield1": "subvalue",
         "subfield2": []
      },
      { 
         "subfield1": "subvalue2",
         "subfield2": [ "string1", "string2", "...", "stringN" ]
      }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the count of objects contained in field2, where subfield2 is empty.

I tried it this way to get all objects where subfield2 is empty:

```
$datas = Get-Content -Path .\data
$json = $datas | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.field2 | Select-Object subfield2 | where subfield2 -Match ".*\[\].*"
```

Executing this results in no output. Using -EQ or -Like doesn't work either.

Comment: The JSON sample is invalid. Please edit the question and add parsable, valid data.

Comment: Sorry, Its valid json now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably many other ways.  This is one.

```
@($json.field2 | Where-Object {$($_.subfield2) -eq $null}).Count
```

Make `$_.subfield2` a string with `$($_.subfield2)`.  Check string for $null.

Comment: That's it! Nice and thanks alot. Is there any  good documentation you can recommend for digging deeper into powershell? I'm very new to it

Comment: "Windows PowerShell in Action" book, use `Get-Help` like ` Get-Help Get-Process -Examples` and search this site for lots of good examples and answers. Use ISE or VSCode to write and debug code.